# Accessing maven repo requiring windows creds with a mac

Tags: java, windows, maven

I'm trying to accessing a server with a maven repo. From my windows machine at work I can access it with my company login. With my mac I can access the server if I connect to it and enter in my windows credentials. 
Here is the part of my pom with the rep:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.id</id>
        <url>file:////servername/MavenRepo</url>
        <!-- use snapshot version -->
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

here is the part of the settings.xml that I'm using to try to set credentials to access that maven repo. What am I doing wrong?

```
<server>
  <id>repo.id</id>
  <username>domain\username</username>
  <password>password</password>
</server>
```

The error is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Company-Project: Could not resolve dependencies for project Company-Project:Company-Project:jar:DEVELOP-1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at Company-ProjectName:Company-ProjectName:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for Company-ProjectName:Company-ProjectName:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact Company-ProjectName:Company-ProjectName:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT from/to com.Company.maven (file:////Server.Company.corpnet.local/JenkinsMavenRepo): Repository path /Server.Company.corpnet.local/JenkinsMavenRepo does not exist, and cannot be created. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I added the error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using windows as a filestore for a maven repo is proprietary. I setup a IIS server (http) pointing to that directory which resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that maven could not find the repository on the file system.

> file:////Server.Company.corpnet.local/JenkinsMavenRepo): Repository path /Server.Company.corpnet.local/JenkinsMavenRepo does not exist

Have you mounted the repository file system correctly?
Check if you can access the directory /Server.Company.corpnet.local/JenkinsMavenRepo in the Terminal.

PS
I always would prefer a repository server such as nexus. Is that an option?